# Sending two form inputs to the console log in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, console.log

I'm learning javascript so this question may seem basic. I have a form that takes email address and a choice from a dropdown menu as inputs. When the button is clicked, I'd like both these inputs to be sent to the console log.

The javascript I'm using below just returns 'null'
How do I send the email AND the option selected from the dropdown menu to the console log?

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form role="form" id="sub_form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
         <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group">
         <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control custom-dropdown">
           <option>Select...</option>
           <option>Design</option>
           <option>Human Resources</option>
           <option>Finance</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large custom-button"> Sign up now </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Change that to `console.log($(this).val());`

Comment: You can also do `$('#email').change(function(){ //....});` instead of that plain js handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```js
document.getElementById('sub_form').onsubmit = function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('email').value, document.getElementById('dropdown').value)
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form role="form" id="sub_form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
         <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group">
         <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control custom-dropdown">
           <option>Select...</option>
           <option>Design</option>
           <option>Human Resources</option>
           <option>Finance</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large custom-button"> Sign up now </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This works perfectly except that it outputs to console.log even when an incorrect email address has been entered.

Comment: that type of validation is hand-made. the only validation html provides is the existence of `@` sign

Answer (score 0):

In event listener.. this is not proerly availabe so use. event listner function receives event object as first parameter. so you can use that ... 
change your code as below.

```
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get email & dropdown value when clicked on <kbd>Sign up now</kbd> button.

```js
document.getElementById('custom-button').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById("custom-email").value);
  console.log(document.getElementById("dropdown").value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form role="form" id="sub_form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
         <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" id="custom-email" class="form-control custom-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group">
         <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control custom-dropdown">
           <option>Select...</option>
           <option>Design</option>
           <option>Human Resources</option>
           <option>Finance</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
  <button type="submit" id="custom-button" class="btn btn-large custom-button"> Sign up now </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```